# Is it possible to in-place upgrade CentOS 7 to 8

Tags: centos, centos7, centos8

Is it possible to upgrade CentOS 7 to 8 without reinstalling the whole server ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from CentOS official site
I just noticed this. https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=71896